# Vue.js dynamic component with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use the `<component>` element to dynamically display a chosen component. Each of these displayed components can take one of any number of data objects. Something like:

```
<div id="containers">
    <component v-bind:is="currentView"></component>
</div>

var myVue = new Vue({
    el:"#containers",
    data:{
        currentView: "my-component-one",
        currentData: {...}
    },
    method: {
        changeView: function(){
            //change this.currentView
            //change this.currentData
        }
    }
});
```

However, the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) says the `v-bind:is` attribute can be used to pass either a component name **or** the options object.

It is unclear how I would conditionally get an object of values for that component to use and also conditionally change which component is shown.

I am very green with using Vue (coming fresh off a knockout kick) so perhaps I am simply misunderstanding the intention of the component tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use `v-bind`

html

```
<component v-bind:is="currentView" v-bind="data"></component>
```

script

```
data()
{
    return {
        data: {
            currentData: "example"
        } 
    }
}
```

and it will pass `currentData` down to child. You can also add other properties along with it, including `is`.

If you need to change the component along with props, then you just change the `data` property, or whatever you want to call it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/7w81o10mlx

Answer (score 1):

This example might help you understand it. https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/mLbrj5gd/

---

**For passing Component Name**

If the component is global, you can pass the component name to `v-bind:is`

for e.g.,

```
Vue.component('test1', {
    template: `<div>test1</div>`
})
```

HTML

```
<component is="test1"></component>
```

---

**For passing option**

A Vue component is literally just a Javascript object with specific properties

for e.g.,

```
  <component v-bind:is="{
    template: `<div>test2</div>`
  }"></component>
```